# Last row still shows <div>

Tags: php, css

I'm learning PHP/MySQLi at the minute and I need help with something I just can't seem to find online. I am using `<div class="hr"> </div>` after every topic in the forum script I am making but I don't want it to display one after the last topic their is, how do I stop my script from displaying it after the last row? I would be grateful for any help and just so I'm a 100% clear.

```
        Here is how it looks:

         Topic Title Here
        -------------------------------------
        Topic Title Here
        -------------------------------------

        But I want:

         Topic Title Here
        -------------------------------------
        Topic Title Here

        My code of where this part is:

             <?php
    }
          $dn2 = mysql_query('select t.id, t.title, t.authorid, u.username
         as author,
      count(r.id) as replies from topics as t left join topics as r on     
        r.parent="'.$id.'"
      and r.id=t.id and r.id2!=1  left join users as u on u.id=t.authorid
      where t.parent="'.$id.'" and t.id2=1 group by t.id order by t.timestamp2 desc');

    if(mysql_num_rows($dn2)>0)
    {
    ?>

    <table id="main-table">
    <tr>
        <td id="side">
                      </td>

        <td id="content">
    <?php
    while($dnn2 = mysql_fetch_array($dn2))
    {
    ?>

        <div><a href="read_topic.php?id=<?php echo $dnn2['id']; ?>">
          <?php echo htmlentities($dnn2['title'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></a>
        - <a class="wtb" href="profile.php?id=<?php echo $dnn2['authorid']; ?>">
           <?php echo htmlentities($dnn2['author'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></a></div>

        <div class="hr"> </div>

<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: You haven't provided enough code to provide a reasonable answer. How about showing how you iterate through your topics as a start.

Comment: You should use css and not an additional html element to draw that line. With the `::after` psuedo element and `:last-of-type` that should be no problem.

Comment: I have edited my post and updated my code.  Thank you jeroen this does sound easier to do but I have read that it's not good practice to do so, well not as good as using PHP anyway?

Comment: It's actually the other way around, you should not use php for the presentation when you can do it with css.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your code, an easy way to fix it would be to draw the line first unless it's the first topic

```
    if ($topicNumber != 1) echo ('<div class="hr"> </div>');
    <div><?php echo $dnn1['topic']; ?><div>
    <? } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this easily with your css:

```
<style>
.wrapper div {border-bottom: 1px dashed black}
.wrapper div:last-child{ border-bottom: 0}
</style>

<div class="wrapper">   

    <div><?php echo $dnn1['topic']; ?><div>
    <? } ?>     

</div>
```